# Comparing nth element of list with another nth element, then swapping if statement true PYTHON 3.4.3

Tags: python, list, element

I've got two lists. Both of them related to a theater's auditorium.
The first list contains the occupancy of the chairs like this:

```
xxooxoxoooxoxo
ooxoxooxoooxox
...
...
```

`x` = occupied, `o` = free

My second list contains the price category of the chairs  like this:

```
33221111112233
33333222233333
...
...
```

I would like to make a 3rd list which shows the price category of the empty chairs like this:

```
3xxx11xx1xx2xx
...
...
```

So basically, I would like to swap the `o`-s with the number of the price categories.

Here's what I've got so far:

My `Rows` list already contains the auditorium's occupancy and my `Category` list the price categories.

```
iRow = -1
icatRow = -1
chairNumber = -1
chairPrice = -1
Row = []
RowCat = []
for row in Rows:
    chairNumber = -1
    iRow += 1
    Row.append(row)
    if Row[iRow][chairNumber] == 'o':
        for cat in Category:
            icatRow += 1
            chairPrice += 1
            RowCat.append(cat)
            RowCat[icatRow][chairPrice] = Row[iRow][chairNumber]
        chairNumber += 1
    else:
        chairNumber += 1
print('{0}\n'.format(Row))
```

I receive the following error in the line `RowCat[icatRow][chairPrice] = Row[iRow][chairNumber]`:

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Could you help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for row, price in zip(rows, prices):
    new_row = ''
    for char,pri in zip(row,price):
        if char == 'o':
             new_row += str(pri)
        else:
              new_row += char

    print(new_row)
```

For sample data

```
rows = ['xoxo','oxox']
prices = ['1234','5678']
```

Note that using strings here is equivalent to using a list of lists as Strings can in many cases be treated as lists in Python (such as iterating through all characters in the string/iterating through all elements of a list)

I get out:

```
x2x4
5x7x
```

You of course would want to change the line `print(new_row)` to do whatever it is you want to do with your manipulated row

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not very pythonic.  Try something like t his.

```
l1 = ['x','o','x']
l2 = [1,2,3]
l3 = [ r if r == 'x' else p for r,p in zip(l1,l2)]
```

returns a new list with

```
['x', 2, 'x']
```

Comment: just for fun: `l3 = [seat[0 if 'x' in seat else 1] for seat in zip(l1,l2)]`

Comment: Or ``map(lambda x: x[0] if x[0]=='x' else x[1] , zip(l1,l2))``

Answer (score 0):

I got the out put like this:

```
def foo2():
    l1 = ['xxooxoxoooxoxo', 'ooxoxooxoooxox']
    l2 = ['33221111112233' , '33333222233333']
    l = []
    for i, row in enumerate(l1):
        t = [x if x is 'x' else l2[i][j] for j,x in enumerate(row) ]
        l.append(''.join(t))
    print l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
>>> list1 = ['x','x','o','o','x','o','x']
>>> list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> list3 = [list2[i] if j == 'o' else j for i, j in enumerate(list1)]
>>> list3
['x', 'x', 3, 4, 'x', 6, 'x']
```